# Grails WebFlow and Command Objects: Only One Command Object allowed?

Tags: grails, spring-webflow, command-objects

Grails 1..3.7

In regular controller actions I can do the following:

```
def someAction = { OneCommand oneCmd, TwoCommand twoCmd ->

}
```

However, in a webflow action I have the equivillent:

```
def someFlow = {
  someAction { 
    on("something") { OneCommand oneCmd, TwoCommand twoCmd ->
    }
  }
}
```

which doesn't bind the params to either object.  If I remove one of them, it binds to the one left.  Is this a bug or expected behavior?

Comment: Looking at the code that's definitely something that is _supposed_ to work...  If you can reproduce the same behaviour in a newly-created minimal demo application then it's probably worth a JIRA, but be warned the response may be "use a newer Grails release"...

Comment: Thanks.  I've upgraded to 2.0.1 think maybe that was the case and it has the same issue.  I'll see if I can put together a small project.